# Vue video files not found after building project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, build

When I do `npm run serve` in my project, I have some videos in

```
myVueProject
  public
    videos 
      hello.mp4
```

In my Vue template I have

```
let a = this.name
this.videoName = '/videos/'+a+'.mp4';
//produces /videos/hello.mp4
//I dynamically change the video src in template
<source :src="videoName" type="video/mp4"
```

This works fine, but when I do npm run build, I get the following structure

```
css
fonts
videos
  hello.mp4
js
index.html
```

and I copy all the above to the public folder of a node server

```
server.js
public
   contains the above structure
conections
setups
```

The app is now served via node server, everything works fine, but the videos are not found

What am I missing here? I am confused about the settings.

Feel free to ask me any details I did not include

Thanks

Comment: Can you fix the "I get the following structure" to be as structure on the server is shown in your question? you do get hello.mp4 inside videos folder I reckon right? Also, when 404 happens, what is the path you see in network tab in  dev tools?

Comment: @trainoasis I edited my question so the structure I get when `npm run build` is now clear. In the network tab, for the video I see `http://localhost/shoes/sales/boys/skate/50005videos/hello.mp` that is weird to me , because in the url, that is a product : `http://localhost/shoes/sales/boys/skate/50005`. I am more confused, please help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe change how you use video path, perhaps via publicPath var https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath, does this help? Since obviously your src is built from the current href. Or you could even just use window.location and extract only what you need out (remove path).